# Opengl tutorials

Tags: opengl, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good learning resources for OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-are-some-good-learning-resources-for-opengl)
>   [Starting out with OpenGL when most tutorials are out of date](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28814/starting-out-with-opengl-when-most-tutorials-are-out-of-date)

I know that there are many questions like this, but i want the best answer how to learn modern opengl from basics.
Also i want to avoid toolkits like glut or similar. Any books or something? 
Using Windows

Answer (score 1):

I think the free online book **Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming** by Jason L. McKesson, username [Nicol Bolas](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/8240/nicol-bolas) on GDSE, is a great place to start.

It does use FreeGLUT to create the window, but I don't really see that as a disadvantage, since it allows most of the Win32 boilerplate code to be skipped, so that the book can actually focus on modern OpenGL programming. You can easily find Win32 programming resources elsewhere, or just use GLFW or SDL.

Link - http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/