# Where to start learning OpenGL with C++?

Tags: opengl, c++, game-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good learning resources for OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-are-some-good-learning-resources-for-opengl)

I have learnt C++ and made some cool text based games and such but I would love to start graphical programming. I'm a decent artist (I will have some of my work below) I know the basics of C++ but I really would like to get into OpenGL.

I need someone to show me some good tutorials for OpenGL with C++ so I can really get into game development. My goal is to be able to program a simple 2D game by the end of the year and I have lots of time to do so. I'm en-rolled in a game development course next year and really need some help with starting off.

Comment: Welcome, Norbert.

Comment: Learning how to properly use Google will definitely help you on your way becoming a programmer, in fact it's essential! Or the search button on this site for that matter: [Good resources for learning modern OpenGL (3.0 or later)?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32876/good-resources-for-learning-modern-opengl-3-0-or-later)

Comment: also [What are some good learning resources for OpenGL?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-are-some-good-learning-resources-for-opengl)

Answer (score 21):

**Pure Basics (for Latest/Modern OpenGL/OpenGL 3D Graphics Programming)**

- http://www.opengl.org/
- http://open.gl/
- http://deslab.mit.edu/DesignLab/13.003/Graphics_Lectures/
- https://graphics.stanford.edu/wikis/cs148-11-fall/Lectures

**Online Resources (for Latest/Modern OpenGL/OpenGL 3D Graphics Programming)**

- https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/
- http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html

**Basics Examples (from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming)**

- [Structure of a Typical OpenGL Application](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/Structure)
- [Drawing Rectangles](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/Rectangles)
- [Drawing Lines and Points](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/LinesPoints)
- [Drawing Simple 2D Shapes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/2DObjects)
- [OpenGL Naming Conventions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/NamingConventions)
- [Using Color](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/Color)
- [Viewing Transformations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Basics/Transformations)

**Intermediate Examples (from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming)**

- [Smoothing Polygons with Normals](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Intermediate/Normals)
- [Adding Lights](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Intermediate/Lighting)
- [Using Textures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Intermediate/Textures)

**Other samples**

- http://openglsamples.sourceforge.net/
- http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/opengl_introduction.html
- http://www.gametutorials.com/gtstore/c-1-test-cat.aspx

**Community Resources**

- [Starting out with OpenGL when most tutorials are out of date](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28814/starting-out-with-opengl-when-most-tutorials-are-out-of-date)
- [What are some good learning resources for OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-are-some-good-learning-resources-for-opengl)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926357/c-opengl-books
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239917/getting-started-with-opengl

Comment: I totally agree with your answer except for the 'Beginning OpenGL Game Programming' book, which seems outdated. (It was long before OpenGL3 was released).

Comment: @RoyT. Yes, I agree with you. I have edited my answer. Thanks for comment. :)

Comment: opengl.org does more harm than good, i'd avoide it like the plague unless somebody wants the pure specification, it's not good for anything else

Comment: @dreta, What would be better in lieu of opengl.org?

Comment: @MahbuburRAaman null and void

Comment: Unfortunately the last two links are now dead

Answer (score 4):

There is a free book, released this year, called "Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming" which I saw John Carmack (from ID/DOOM fame) recommend. You can browse it here https://learnopengl.com/arcsynthesis.pdf I've been going through it myself to learn more about the 'proper' way to do things in OpenGL.  Now I realize this is in C, not C++. But since OpenGL is mostly a C API its best to learn it this way and then later encapsulate it in objects later if you want to and of course all the C code works perfectly fine in C++.

As for other tutorials and books. There are a lot of old ones out there which learn you a lot of bad practices (that used to be good practices). Shun away from anything that is using the fixed pipeline functions like `glVertex`, `glColor`, the matrix stack, the gluPerspective and gluLookAT functions. These are all depricated and outdated. Try to write as clean as possible OpenGL 3.

Comment: Happen to remember where you saw John Carmack recommending that book?

Comment: He said something like "A very decent looking book on modern OpenGL" on twitter. Must've been not more than a month before I answered this question.

Comment: Link is not working anymore. Is it this book: https://learnopengl.com/arcsynthesis.pdf ?

Comment: @antibus thanks, that's the one. I've updated the URL.