# Game Development at iOS, Android and PC with OpenGL ES

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, cross-platform, pc

I'm beginning iOS apps development, and my aim is to make games to launch on App Store.
But I want to know if it's possible to program a game on Xcode with OpenGL ES (C++ game logic), integrate it on iOS with ObjC, and with that same game code (OpenGL ES + C++), implement it for Android with Java and to PC.

I have great interest to publish the same game on App Store, Google Play and specially Steam, and intent to build my personal 2D engine/API when I have more experience on graphic programming.

Do you know where can I find material to learn this?

Comment: take a look at [cocos2d-x](http://cocos2d-x.com)

Answer (score 4):

You can use OpenGL ES 2.0 in C/C++ code in both platforms - Android and iOS. No need to use Java or Objective-C for calling OpenGL functions. As long as you don't use vendor/hardware specific OpenGL extensions your drawing code can stay exactly same for both platforms.

- iOS has OpenGL ES 2.0 in C++ support natively
- Android supports OpenGL ES 2.0 in C++ through [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html)
- To utilize the same OpenGL ES 2.0 in C++ code in PC, give a try to
  [ANGLE](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) which translates OpenGL-ES calls to Direct3D.

For, C++ OpenGL Resources

- [Where to start learning OpenGL with C++?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/42187/where-to-start-learning-opengl-with-c)
- [What are some good learning resources for OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/what-are-some-good-learning-resources-for-opengl)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926357/c-opengl-books

Comment: C# is another lovely language. Available on Windows as .net, on Android as Mono for Android, and on iOS as MonoTouch. In addition, it's available on the PS Vita as PlayStation Mobile (let me see your C/C++ do _that_). This is especially relevant on Android, because you don't have to go down to the NDK.

Comment: @PandaPajama, You are absolutely right. I agree with You. Thanks for your informative comment. :)